# Using enum class for defining flags

Tags: c++, c++11, enum-class

**What is the appropriate pattern for using enumerations as flags in modern C++?**

The question stems from my reading of the technical specification [A Proposal to Add 2D Graphics Rendering and Display to C++](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N4021.pdf), where McLaughlin, Sutter, and Zink propose a C++ API for 2D graphics based on the [Cairo API](http://cairographics.org/manual/).

Throughout the API declaration, the authors make full use of C++11. In particular, their enumerations are all declared like:

```
enum class font_slant {
  normal,
  italic,
  oblique
};
```

Except for a single one:

```
namespace text_cluster_flags {
  enum text_cluster_flags : int {
    none     = 0x0,
    backward = 0x1
  };
}
```

The `text_cluster_flags` "type" is used in a class method:

```
void show_text_glyphs(const ::std::string& utf8,
    const ::std::vector<glyph>& glyphs,
    const ::std::vector<text_cluster>& clusters,
    text_cluster_flags cluster_flags);
```

I assume the extraneous declaration is so that the `text_cluster_flags` can be masked, as in:

```
auto flag = text_cluster_flags::none | text_cluster_flags::backward;
```

which you cannot do with `enum class` enumerations:

```
enum class flags {
  a = 0x0,
  b = 0x1
};

auto f = flags::a | flags::b; // error because operator `|` is
                              // not defined for enum class flags
                              // values
```

Should the authors have defined the masking operators? Or is their *enum-within-namespace* pattern effective practice?

Comment: I'd say this would fit better on the Programmers Stack Exchange since your question is largely conceptual.

Comment: @alexroussos when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Answer (score 2):

It's modelled after the [cairo API](https://web.archive.org/web/20130831050514/http:/cairographics.org/manual/).

For `font_slant` we can see cairo's equivalent:

> **enum cairo_font_slant_t**
>
> ```
> typedef enum {
>     CAIRO_FONT_SLANT_NORMAL,
>     CAIRO_FONT_SLANT_ITALIC,
>     CAIRO_FONT_SLANT_OBLIQUE
> } cairo_font_slant_t;
> ```
>
> Specifies variants of a font face based on their slant.
>
> `CAIRO_FONT_SLANT_NORMAL` Upright font
>   style, since 1.0
>
> `CAIRO_FONT_SLANT_ITALIC` Italic font
>   style, since 1.0
>
> `CAIRO_FONT_SLANT_OBLIQUE` Oblique font
>   style, since 1.0

For `text_cluster_flags` we can see cairo's equivalent:

> **enum cairo_text_cluster_flags_t**
>
> ```
> typedef enum {
>     CAIRO_TEXT_CLUSTER_FLAG_BACKWARD = 0x00000001
> } cairo_text_cluster_flags_t;
> ```
>
> Specifies properties of a text cluster mapping.
>
> `CAIRO_TEXT_CLUSTER_FLAG_BACKWARD` The
>   clusters in the cluster array map to glyphs in the glyph array from
>   end to start. (Since 1.8)

The function `text_to_glyphs` models `cairo_show_text_glyphs`, which takes a `cairo_text_cluster_flags_t`. Furthermore, the API has a function for getting the current slant. So my guess is:

- `enum class` is meant for *strong typing* of a flag. It doesn't make any sense to have something that's both "normal" and "italic". These are attached to a "font face".
- `text_cluster_flags` is a one-time deal. If you set it for the show glyphs function, it simply changes the behavior. It's not attached to a "text cluster" like slant is attached to a "font face". There's no reason for strong typing here.

Your interpretation was correct btw. Here's a snippet of the source code:

```
// ...

+       const cairo_glyph_t *cur_glyph;
+
+       if (cluster_flags & CAIRO_TEXT_CLUSTER_FLAG_BACKWARD)
+       cur_glyph = glyphs + num_glyphs - 1;
+       else
+       cur_glyph = glyphs;
+
+       for (i = 0; i < num_clusters; i++) {
+       cairo_bool_t cluster_visible = FALSE;
+

// ...
```